# Indexes Without Where Clause

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Let's say I have the following query:

```
select col_1, col_2, col_3
from table
order by col_1;
```

I *only* have an index on col_1.

Would an index be used efficiently here? I don't have a where clause, but I do have "Order By," so I am wondering.

Edit Part 2: Let's pretend that I have a table with 1 million rows.

Edit to provide Context of Question:

I was reading a book about database administration and this is what it said:

```
SELECT last_name, first_name, middle_initial, empno, position
FROM employee
WHERE position IN ('MANAGER', 'DIRECTOR', 'VICE PRESIDENT')
ORDER BY last_Name;
```

"If an index exists on the last_name column, the query can use this index and avoid sorting . . ."

So I started thinking that "sorting" would be faster if I created an index on the column that I plan to always sort on, even if the rest of my query is missing where, group by, having, etc.

Comment: Check your query plan.

Comment: without using limit the most efficient method would be a full table scan every time for that query

Comment: Indexes are supposed to help with sorting, or so I have just read, so I thought if I used an index on a query that just has "Order By" and no "Where" clause, it would be used efficiently.

Comment: @Lucas why would a full table scan be the most efficient method for this query?

Comment: largely an index is a separate piece of information that is used to help find specific results, your query is not specifying anything other than "give me all the values ordered by col1" - you ask for all the results then you get all the results - in computer terms it is a choice between fetch everything and sorting it, over going back and forth between two files to fetch the lot and sort

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. So in order to use an index efficiently in a SQL query, you pretty much have to use a where clause or it will do a full table scan every time then?

Comment: for simplicities sake, yes

Comment: @Lucas I must agree with OP. Index scan should be more efficient then seq scan with sort. Though, `EXPLAIN` will give more accurate answer here.

Comment: I edited my post to provide more context for this question.

Comment: @LunchBox you should really familiarize yourself with postgres query planer and `EXPLAIN` command. This way you'll get quicker and more precise answers on index usage in different queries.

Comment: Thanks @Leonid Beschastny! Will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear things up here I made a simple simulation.

First, I've created an empty table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE so_test (
  col_1 bigint,
  col_2 bigint,
  col_3 bigint
);

CREATE INDEX col_1 ON so_test USING btree (col_1);
```

And run two `EXPLAIN` queries:

```sql
explain select col_1, col_2, col_3
from so_test
order by col_1;
```

```
Index Scan using col_1 on so_test  (cost=0.15..66.80 rows=1510 width=24)
```

```sql
explain select col_1, col_2, col_3
from so_test
order by col_2;
```

```
Sort  (cost=104.83..108.61 rows=1510 width=24)
  Sort Key: col_2
  ->  Seq Scan on so_test  (cost=0.00..25.10 rows=1510 width=24)
```

So, having an index on `col_1` will completely eliminate any need to perform a sort operation and somewhat speed things up.

Though, to see a considerable speedup from adding an index you should use query with `LIMIT`.

In future you should familiarize yourself with postgres query planer and [`EXPLAIN` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html). This way you'll get quicker and more precise answers on index usage in different queries.

Comment: Thanks Leonid! I know you can speed things up with LIMIT, but I just wanted to understand how indexes affect performance in different scenarios!  I have roughly 5 months of data analyst experience, so I am pretty inexperienced. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: @LunchBox I meant that sort query with limit will require a full table scan unless you have an index. So adding an index may considerably speedup such queries. But without a limit postgres will have to load the full data set anyway, so the difference won't be so huge.

Comment: Using an index or not, without limit, a full table scan will still be done for both queries?

Comment: Yes. The only difference is that having an index will skip an expensive sort operation.

Comment: As you may see from explain queries output, without an index postgres will use a very fast seq scan operation and then an expensive sort operation, while with an index it'll use a single index scan (which is slower than seq scan, but still faster than seq scan with sort).